# How do I view doc/txt/enc file in browser

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I need to view a doc/txt/enc file from my server but whenever I enter its url in my browser it automatically downloads the file. I just want to view it using a `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`
Like this one
[image]

Edit:
I want it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: If you use `text/plain` with a doc you'll only see the bytecode, not a meaningful content :) that's what mime type is meant to

Comment: Yeah I want that. I actually want to see the content of my .enc file because it is a `json`

Comment: a JSON is a JSON, an enc is an enc. A JSON requires `application/json` while enc another thing

Comment: I have no idea if it is served differently in backend

Comment: Can you edit the server to set the proper headers?

Comment: That's a JSON that contains an enc. The response header should be set to `application/json`, because it's just formatted text. The browser doesn't care what's the content, so you'll have to handle it at another level. You have to setup your backend in order to create that object and then deliver it to the client

Comment: yeah. I am using nodejs. Do you know how do I set the headers?

Comment: You can set it as any other header, but if you use `res.json(...)` it will be set automatically

Comment: @CristianTraìna My problem is the file url is statically served on my backend inside the /public folder so I did not use `res.json` or anything

Comment: I'll attempt a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what's said in the comments, you can change the code that serves statically your folder:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public', {
  setHeaders: (res, path) => {
    if (path.endsWith('.enc')) {
      res.type('application/json');
    }
  }
}));
```